# SQL Server latitude and longitude data type

Tags: sql-server, google-maps

I want to ask about what SQL Server data type to use for storing latitude and longitude.

Here's an example:

```
Latitude: -7.39755000
Longitude: 107.80627000
```

If data type `decimal`, it won't save because SQL Server said:

> cannot convert numeric data to numeric

as I remembered.

But if type data was `float`, SQL Server will convert `0` so the latitude will be `-7.39755000`. So I figure it out replace the last `0` with `1 - 9`. is it the location will be not accurate?

Or maybe stick with `decimal`, but how to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`DECIMAL(9,6)` is what I normally use for both. If you need more precision, then try `DECIMAL(12,9)`.

You could also use the `GEOGRAPHY` data type, but it will take more space, and I would only recommend this if you need SQL Servers spatial features (indexing etc).

For the actual conversion, try this:

```
CAST(@YourLat AS DECIMAL(12,9))
```

Comment: Is it that query for selecting. When i save data with data type decimal (10,8) it got error, it say `arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric` @g2server

Comment: DECIMAL(10,8) won't work since Long and Lat can have the format xxx.xxxxxx. (10,8 is xx.xxxxxxxx). So, try DECIMAL(12,9)

Comment: @g2server Latitude has the range `[-90;90]` so it could be stored in `DECIMAL(8,6)`. Longitude has the range `[-180;180]` so it should be stored in `DECIMAL(9,6)`. For consistency I think `DECIMAL(9,6)` for both should be preferred.